# When should use Managed Extensibility Framework?

Tags: mef

I refereed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx#the_problem_of_extensibility) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework) link for Managed Extensibility Framework. but still not totally clear some of parts. I am confuse about.... In which scenario should be used MEF and why?

Is there any other example of MEF?

Answer (score 2):

MEF is especially useful for large applications where injecting the dependencies between distant parts would get hard to manage as the size of the code base increases. I find that large GUI applications written using MVVM can greatly benefit from an IoC container like MEF.

The basics of MEF are telling it what to create then telling it where you can find the types that it should be creating.

I also suggest checking out the [Prism Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.events.ieventaggregator.aspx), which also helps reduce and clean up the coupling of a large application.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little article about it (in french at first but tranlate by Bing) that you can read [Here](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http://blog.mic-belgique.be/articles/mef-managed-extensibility-framework/)